# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions not capturing shadows / gradients

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-core

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to save a screenshot into a UIImage. While this works, the resulting UIImage is missing any shadows and gradients.

How do I get it to also screenshot the layer stuff?

---

**TEST CODE SHOWING THE PROBLEM**

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //super
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //background
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //container
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:container];

    //circle
    UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 10)];
    circle.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    circle.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    circle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    circle.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    circle.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
    circle.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 30, 30)].CGPath;
    [container addSubview:circle];

    //screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(container.bounds.size, container.opaque, 0.0);
    [container.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //image view
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 568-200-20-10, 300, 200)];
    iv.image = screenshot;
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
}

@end
```

---

**SIMULATOR SCREENSHOT SHOWING THE PROBLEM**

---

The top area is the original view. The bottom area is a UIImageView with the screenshot.

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Comment: [[circle layer] setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: Just tried setNeedsDisplay. Called it every other line just to be safe. Still no shadow in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In this line ,

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(container.bounds.size, container.opaque, 0.0);

```
put NO instead of container.opaque
```

Use this method ,

```
- (UIImage *)imageOfView:(UIView *)view
{

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    }

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, still not capturing the red part

Answer (score 0):

For drop shadow on an Image:

```
public func generateShadow(for image: UIImage, shadowOffset: CGSize,blur: CGFloat, shadowColor: CGColor ) -> UIImage? {
let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width + blur, height:
                    image.size.height +  blur)

return MediaPickerFramework.generateImage(CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.width), contextGenerator: { size, context in
    context.clear(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size))
            context.setShadow(offset: shadowOffset,
                              blur: blur,
                              color: shadowColor)
            let center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
            let imageOrigin = CGPoint(x: center.x - (image.size.width / 2), y: center.y - (image.size.height / 2))
    
            context.draw(image.cgImage!,
                         in: CGRect(x: imageOrigin.x, y: imageOrigin.y, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height),
                         byTiling:false)
})
```

}

and for draw Gradient on an image, you can use the below function

```
 func generateGradientTintedImage(image: UIImage?, colors: [UIColor]) -> UIImage? {
guard let image = image else {
    return nil
}

let imageSize = image.size

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, image.scale)
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: imageSize)
    context.saveGState()
    context.translateBy(x: imageRect.midX, y: imageRect.midY)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.translateBy(x: -imageRect.midX, y: -imageRect.midY)
    context.clip(to: imageRect, mask: image.cgImage!)
    
    let gradientColors = colors.map { $0.cgColor } as CFArray
    let delta: CGFloat = 1.0 / (CGFloat(colors.count) - 1.0)
    
    var locations: [CGFloat] = []
    for i in 0 ..< colors.count {
        locations.append(delta * CGFloat(i))
    }
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: gradientColors, locations: &locations)!
    
    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: imageRect.height), end: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions())
    
    context.restoreGState()
}

let tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return tintedImage
```

}